# JMS / ActiveMQ Transaction Timeout

Tags: transactions, jms, activemq-classic

I've been having problems with setting the transaction timeout for ActiveMQ.

I want to set the timeout on a message so if it isn't committed within a certain period, then rollback() is then called.

I'm not sure whats the best way to go about this - whether it is set on the activemq configuration or it is done at the time the message is created. Also, whether its solely handled by jms or activemq or a bit of both.

Thanks for your time

Comment: JTA or JMS (session) transactions? there's a difference...